# mysql return matching other rows when one table returns 0

Tags: mysql, subquery

Simply put:

```
SELECT
  table1.field1,
  table2.field2,
  table3.field_WHAT
FROM
  table1,
  table2,
  table3
WHERE
  table1.field1 = 'HELP'
  and table2.field1 = table1.field1
  and table3.field2 = table2.field2
```

I still want all matching rows from table1 & table2, even when no matching record found for table3.field2 ... and *ideally* if no match, `table3.field_WHAT` would return `""` or `NULL`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To format a code block, no need to manually build syntax highlighting!  Highlight the code and click the `{}` editor button or `ctl-k`, resulting in 4-space indentation and free syntax highlighting.

Comment: Avoid comma-join syntax. Always use explicit JOIN syntax. Problems like this will instantly vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  table1.field1,
  table2.field2,
  table3.field_WHAT
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table3 ON table3.field2 = table2.field2
WHERE
  table1.field1 = 'HELP'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case for an `outer join`:

```
SELECT
  table1.field1,
  table2.field2,
  table3.field_WHAT
FROM
  table1,
JOIN 
  table2 ON table2.field1 = table1.field1
OUTER JOIN
  table3 ON table3.field2 = table2.field2
WHERE
  table1.field1 = 'HELP'
```